# Move listview row to textboxes

Tags: vb.net, listview, textbox, click

I'm working with a ListView box for the first time.  I've figured out how to populate it with data from a database.  I now want to click one line of that ListView and have it return each of the five cells from that line into 5 textboxes.  I've written the following code that is failing:

```
Private Sub lvPrinterSetup_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lvPrinterSetup.Click
        Dim values As New List(Of String)
        If lvPrinterSetup.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            For Each item As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In lvPrinterSetup.SelectedItems(0).SubItems
                values.Add(item.Text)
                txbRow.Text = Convert.ToString(lvPrinterSetup.SelectedItems(0))
                txbPrinterName.Text = Convert.ToString(lvPrinterSetup.SelectedItems(1))
                txbPrinterName.Text = Convert.ToString(lvPrinterSetup.SelectedItems(2))
                txbPrinterNo.Text = Convert.ToString(lvPrinterSetup.SelectedItems(3))
                txbPrinterAddress.Text = Convert.ToString(lvPrinterSetup.SelectedItems(4))
            Next

        End If
End Sub
```

This is failing with error notes saying the .SelectedItems(1) "InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index"

I'm sure that 2 - 4  will fail as well too.  So how do I get these 5 items from one line that I've clicked into the various textboxes?

In advance, thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are running a for each loop on a single value (lvPrinterSetup.SelectedItems(0)). Should you not be getting each value from the whole listbox? (lvPrinterSetup.SelectedItems)?

I juts got out of bed, so don't think to much into what i'm writing yet.